# Função JavaScript não aguarda o término de outra para iniciar

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Problema

Minha função não está aguardando a outra ser finalizada para ela poder continuar, por exemplo:

### Exemplo:

```
function buscando_dados(){
   $.post('ajax.php',{},function(dados){
      alert(dados); 
   });
}
function buscar_dados(){
   buscando_dados();
   alert('prosseguindo'); //Prosseguindo está função sem esperar a outra acabar a requisição
}
```

Eu não sei como fazer para o `alert('prosseguindo');` ser executado só depois do `alert('dados');` e no momento não está acontecendo isso.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Esse é uma ótima pergunta, por que ela recebeu negativo? Me ajudou bastante, não posso aceitar isso. :S

Comment: "ansiosa" é um adjetivo que não pode ser atribuído a um programa de computador, é a mesma coisa de ter perguntas aqui com um titulo "Função esperançosa" ou "Função confiante", não foi eu que negativei mas acredito que entendo o motivo.

Comment: Parem de brigar, não sejam ansiosos.

Comment: Por que essa pergunta tem a tag [tag:php]?

Comment: @LuizVieira porque ele faz uma requisição ajax para o php

Comment: Tá, mas isso não é o foco da pergunta, certo?

Comment: @LuizVieira certo, vou tirar..

Comment: Eu acho que faz sentido tirar. Não tirei porque, afinal, a pergunta é sua. :)

Comment: Realmente não tinha necessidade da tag php rs..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sua função `buscando_dados` executa o metodo `POST` do `jQuery` que faz uma requisição assíncrona em AJAX você precisa prosseguir com a execução apos o callback da `função` POST.

Uma solução para oque você quer, pode ser isso.

```
function buscando_dados(func){
   $.post('ajax.php',{},function(dados){
      func.call(this,dados);
   });
}
function buscar_dados(){
   buscando_dados(function(dados){
       alert('prosseguindo'); //Prosseguindo está função sem esperar a outra acabar a 
   });

}
```

passamos uma função por parâmetro que é executada no `callback` da função POST;

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar também o Ajax de forma síncrona.

```
function buscando_dados(){
   $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
   $.post('ajax.php',{},function(dados){
      alert(dados); 
   });
   $.ajaxSetup({async: true});
}

function buscar_dados(){
   buscando_dados();
   alert('prosseguindo');
}
```

#### Exemplo em [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/96f25/).